# Wufoo form is not loading custom stylesheet

Tags: css, forms, wufoo

I have a wufoo form that I am trying to customize with css. My css form is being uploaded as far as I can tell, but so far I haven't been able to change anything. Any tips?

The only thing I've tried to do is change the header color like so:

```
 .wufoo .info h2 {
 color:blue;
 }
```

Here are the necessary links:

Stylesheet - http://crimsonroot.com/files/php/custom.css

Form - https://thedrawshop.wufoo.com/forms/r60xxmf0kwbb7j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as far as I can tell is that you are trying to link to a stylesheet, that is not on an secure connection. Basically it's `http` but your form is secured `https`. Many browsers by default prevent the loading of "mixed content" you will need them to both be on the same connection style before it will even begin to load.

Hope that helps.

Also try this, tested and works.
http://thedrawshop.wufoo.com/forms/r60xxmf0kwbb7j/

Comment: Thanks @natejd04 ! Is there a way I can load it using my current connection? do I need to change the https to http on the style sheet source?

Comment: @Gabriel if you can make both your form source and css source use the same connection either https or http you should be all set. Not sure exactly how wufoo does things, but https is highly recommended if your are storing or processing fragile information. It looks like http works no problem, as long as they are both the same. But I would use caution if the information is privileged since http is vulnerable. Does that help?

Comment: It sure does! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and then I hosted it on Github but it seems that Wufoo is still not loaded it even if it was imported correctly when you check the source.

What I did was to host it instead on Dropbox. I used the sharing link and then added raw=1 at the end.

E.g. https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2fhvsk83fnebw3/wufoo.css?raw=1

That did the trick for me. I hope it helps.